# Tab completion hangs

Tags: bash, autocomplete, automounting

When I first open a terminal, or open a new one after not having used one for a while, any kind of tab completion in my home directory (for example, `ls` and <kbd>Tab</kbd>) takes several seconds. I have seen this behavior before when using `autofs` to mount network drives, but I don't have any in `~/`. I do mount NFS shares with systemd's automount, but those are in `~/badabing/`, so everything in `~/` itself is just a local file.

In case it is an automount issue, here are the relevant `/etc/fstab` lines (yes, the server is called "badabing", I named it during a Sopranos binge a few years ago):

```
badabing:/nfs_shares/music /mnt/badabing/music    nfs4  noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=5sec,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min    0 0
badabing:/nfs_shares/series /mnt/badabing/series  nfs4  noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=5sec,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min    0 0
badabing:/nfs_shares/movies /mnt/badabing/movies  nfs4  noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=5sec,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min    0 0
```

Then, in `~/badabing` I have:

```
$ ls -l ~/badabing/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 32 Jan 10  2016 movies -> /mnt/badabing/nfs_shares/movies/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 31 Jan 10  2016 music -> /mnt/badabing/nfs_shares/music/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 31 Jan 10  2016 series -> /mnt/badabing/nfs_shares/series
```

I'd like to investigate this more. Can I somehow `strace` tab completion? Is the only way to add `echo` commands in the various bash completion scripts to see what's hanging? There are quite a few of those so I'd really rather avoid that.

So, what's causing this or, at least, how can I debug it further?

Comment: You can run strace against a given process, and see where the bash process is spending time.  Adding echo's to scripts won't show you issues in tab completion.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I was thinking of the scripts in `/usr/share/bash-completion` which are run when bash tries to complete something. How would I run strace here though? I can't do `strace bash 2>log` since that will hang. Ah, I just saw that I can attach `strace` to an already running process. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: That's the `-p` option of [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

Comment: @ThomasDickey yeah, just tried that but it seems to run and exit immediately. How can I keep it running while I test things in the straced bash session?

Comment: Perhaps you attached to a child process.  If you attach to the parent process and use the `-f` option, that will follow the (new) child processes.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I get a `strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 31947): Operation not permitted` error for that. This is getting a bit long for the comments. Could you post an answer explaining how I can attach `strace` in such a way as to allow me to follow what happens when I try to autocomplete something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
sudo strace -pXXXX -tfo /tmp/strace.log
```

where *XXXX* is the process id of bash.  In a quick check of filename completion on one of my NFS-mounted directory trees, it works without problems:

> **`-f`**
>
> Trace child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a result of the fork(2) system call.
>
> **`-t`**
>
> Prefix each line of the trace with the time of day.

Some people might prefer `-r`:

> **`-r`**
>
> Print a relative timestamp upon entry to each system call. This records the time difference between the beginning of successive system calls.

Comment: strace hangs and can't be closed.

Comment: My problem is it doesn't hang if I try stracing it. Maybe it's the duration of time that passes until I manage to setup strace.

Comment: You can get the newest bash PID by running pgrep. That way you can save some setup time `sudo strace -p$(pgrep -n [b]ash) -tfo /tmp/strace.log`. However the problem persists for me that I can't measure the issue, since if this other bash is open, the auto-completion doesn't hang for me.

Answer (score 2):

Run `set -x` to get a trace of every shell command, even those executed by the completion framework.

Run `strace -f -p 1234` from another shell to see a trace of system calls. If you get the error “Operation not permitted”, it may be due to a security restriction that restricts the `ptrace` system call to children of the tracing process.¹ To disable this restriction, run `sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0` as root. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process for more information. Alternatively, you can still start a shell with `strace -T -f -o strace.bash bash` (`-T` adds the time spent in each system call) and do your experiments from there.

¹  <sub>This restriction limits the impact of running a malicious application from your account. It's only effective if coupled with many other restrictions (typically effected with SELinux or AppArmor), in particular to limit the restricted process to a small set of files. Even in restricted ptrace mode, the typical use case for ptrace, which is for a debugger to debug a child process, remains allowed.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
PS4='Line ${LINENO}: ' bash -x /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ls
```

Comment: Its not clear to me as a neophyte what this command does. Could you help by explaining it

Comment: The command **PS4='Line ${LINENO}: ' bash -x XYZ** goes line by line through the script XYZ and prints each line with line number. The command includes subscripts and you don’t have to modify the script (like set -X). This is useful if you want to debug scripts.

Comment: The '-x' or `xtrace` option tells Bash to print each command it runs as it runs it. The value of the `PS4` environment variable is expanded and displayed at the beginning of each line, and `$LINENO` is set to the number of whatever line it's executing in the script.