# dnf tab completion hangs

Tags: bash, fedora, autocomplete, dnf

Tab completion is hanging when attempting to complete package names. eg `dnf info fire[TAB]`. How can I fix this?

It works in general for bash, and also for completing `dnf` options, but not for package names. It appears to freeze the command line and I have to hit Ctrl-C twice to get back the command prompt.

Tab completion used to work on Fedora 28, and this issue started after upgrading to Fedora 29.

I have the `bash-completion` and `sqlite` packages installed, which are required for completion.

Using `sudo strace -pXXXX -fro /tmp/strace.log` (where XXXX is the process ID of the bash terminal where tab completion is being attempted) from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324501/tab-completion-hangs/324530#324530) generated a 9MB 80k+ line log file and attached 55 processes. Suggestions of what hints to look for in there?

---

**Observations on `dnf` package name tab completion**

- does not work for my user
- works for root
- does not work after `dnf install` or `dnf info`
- works after `dnf remove` (including for my user)

Comment: Any repeated patterns, such as reading the same file over and over would be an indication. You might also want to "massage" the data to remove timestamps and such, and use `sort | uniq -c | sort -k1 -n` (untested) to see if there are any lines which stand out as extremely frequent.

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks. By not including timestamps and using your commands plus reverse sorting, here are the lines that show up 10 or more times in the log file: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/DQ1rt0t63463sS6xbFE-bg Any clues?

Comment: @l0b0 I noticed in the full log file that there are some `EACCES (Permission denied)` entries regarding access to `/var/lib/rpm` and files within it such as `.dbenv.lock` and `.rpm.lock`. Also in that directory is a binary file `Packages` that is ~300MB, is that normal? I'm just making blind guesses here...

Comment: @adatum Did you find a solution in the end? This issue affects me too and I am unable to find a solution

Comment: Finally fixed it! This bug and (the path to) its solution are described here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1625674

Comment: @delanicolai Thanks, this solved it for me too! You can write up the solution and I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are some workarounds here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1625674. At some point there will be also a fix.

Answer (score 1):

DNF completions is a piece of garbage developed and crafted by redhat.

I do this to remove trash:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dnf
```

NOTE: You may need this command again after updating/upgrading DNF

Answer (score -1):

There are many thousands of packages in the repository. TAB-expansion of package names *will* take a long time. Be patient... or don't do it.